# Read lines with specific NewLine char sequence with StreamReader.ReadLine

Tags: c#, stream, delimiter, streamreader, readline

Sometimes we need to read lines from a stream, but considering only specific char sequence as newline (CRLF, but not CR or LF).

`StreamReader.ReadLine`, as documented, treats as newline sequence CRLF, CR and LF. That may be unacceptable if the line can contain single CR ("\r") or single LF ("\n") as business-valued data.

Need to have ability to read stream line-by-line, but delimited by certain character sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that reads line from stream and returns it as a string:

```
    public static string ReadLineWithFixedNewlineDelimeter(StreamReader reader, string delim)
    {
        if (reader.EndOfStream)
            return null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(delim))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var delimCandidatePosition = 0;
        while (!reader.EndOfStream && delimCandidatePosition < delim.Length)
        {
            var c = (char)reader.Read();
            if (c == delim[delimCandidatePosition])
            {
                delimCandidatePosition ++;
            }
            else
            {
                delimCandidatePosition = 0;
            }
            sb.Append(c);
        }
        return sb.ToString(0, sb.Length - (delimCandidatePosition == delim.Length ? delim.Length : 0));
    }
```